# Help to understand a specific SNOWTAM

Tags: air-traffic-control, notam, meteorology, aim, snowtam

My questions are:

1. According to the article ''**H**''; what about the other runway/runways when I want to add extra info other runway/runways too; there is just one runway in here?
2. According  to the article ''**J**''  it is indicated that critical snowbanks; but it is again just 1 runway I think so.
3. According to the article ''**P**'' 15 is the meter of this taxiway snowbank but in which direction is 15 mt.?

I did not fill any SNOWTAM format so; I want to ask in advance.. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference: ICAO Annex 15, Appendix 2](https://www.skybrary.aero/bookshelf/books/2361.pdf)

> According to the article ''H''; what about the other runway/runways when I want to add extra info other runway/runways too; there is just one runway in here?

A SNOWTAM is for a single runway, if you want to involve multiple runways, you would release more than one SNOWTAM.

> According to the article ''J'' it is indicated that critical snowbanks; but it is again just 1 runway I think so.

Yes, this is just for the runway identified in C).

> According to the article ''P'' 15 is the meter of this taxiway snowbank but in which direction is 15 mt.?

This is the distance *between* snowbanks in meters. There is no direction there as it just identifies a relative distance between two (or more) objects.